# i am not able to find mainactivity.java fle and layout folder

Tags: java, android, ios, windows, android-studio

[in this image i show my folder structure]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbQ6s.png)

i am not able to find 'Mainactivity.java' file and 'layout' folder

please help me.

thanks you !

Comment: hello Dhainik please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn a few things about how to provide a good question. Please write some paragraphs about what you tried and why that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to Invalidate cache/Restart and select to Project structure rather than Android. You will find the required files if they really exists.

Comment: Switch to Project mode to find it.

Comment: Are you able to see it or not?